# Throwing exceptions in Controller methods Play framework?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework, exception, controller

I am using Play framework (2.5) for Java development. In that, we configure routes and for those routes the relative controller methods to be triggered.

I have a question whether is it OK to include exception throws in these controller method signatures or we must catch them inside the method body?

**EX:**

```
public Result getPurchasedStatisticsOutOfAllPriceChecked(String from, String to) throws InvalidParameterException, SalesServiceException {

        RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams(messageProvider);
        requestParams.setDateRangeStart(from);
        requestParams.setDateRangeEnd(to);

        return ok(processInfluenceOnSales(influenceOnOverallSales));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way is to handle those Exceptions inside your Action method, instead of throwing. By this you can respond to the client with relevant error message, otherwise you end up with

> 500 Internal server error

and your stacktrace looks like following `play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception` followed by respective exception trace.

Comment: thanks for ur response.  what do you mean by action method here?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Action methods are one, who process incoming  request and serve desired response to client. In your method `getPurchasedStatisticsOutOfAllPriceChecked` whose  return type is `Result`. So it's a action method. More info about Action defined [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActions)